# Is " of him" or " for him " followed by the infinitive?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, infinitive-clauses

> 1. It's hard **for you** to make such a decision.

> 2. It's very kind **of you** to see me off.

Either of the above sentences works well. Here arises a question about how to use the prepositional phrase preceding the infinitive?
For example,

> 3. It is wise **of him** ( or "**for him**" ?) to say so.

Comment: If you think _he_ finds it hard/difficult... it is <adjective> **for** him. If _you_ find his action kind/wise... it is <adjective> **of** him. We use "of you" when we ascribe the characteristic or quality, and "for you" when we know, deduce or assume it.

Comment: A point about the grammar; "of" is a prep, but the "for" in your example is a subordinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a construction like

> It is [adjective] [of/for] him to [verb phrase]

Here are some general rules:

We can use **of him** whenever the adjective could reasonably be applied to him. This can often be tricky, so here are a few examples:

> It's cruel **of you** to leave me here in the cold. **✔** (*you are cruel*) 
> It's cool **of him** to give so much money away. **✔** (*he is cool*) 
> It's surprising **of her** to do that. **X** (*she is surprising? dosn't really work*) 
> It's unfair **of you** to give her more than me. **✔** (*you are unfair*) 
> It's hard **of you** to make such a decision. **X** (*you are hard?*)

We can use **for him** in general when *of him* doesn't apply, but also when the adjective applies to the person in question specifically and would not apply to just anyone in that person's shoes. I'll explain this more below, but first, here are some examples of the first and simplest case:

> It was huge **for him** to score this win. **✔** (*he is not huge*) 
> It was dangerous **for him** to climb up there. **✔** (*he is not dangerous*)

The second case is somewhat more complex. Sometimes we use **for you** to emphasize the circumstances of the person in question. Immagine the following two scenarios:

> A) A group of gang members walks up to John. They ask him "Do you support our gang?" John says, "Yes, I love your gang!" They let him go without bothering him. 
> B) A group of gang members walks up to John. They ask him "Do you support our gang?" John says, "No, I don't support gangs." They rob John and then let him go.

In scenario (A), it was **wise for John** to express support for the gang because of the particulars of his circumstance. In other words, because of the nature of **John's specific circumstance**, it was smart. In scenario (B), it was **wise of John** to say that he doesn't support gangs; in fact, it would be wise of everyone to do so **regardless of their circumstance**. In scenario (A), you can use **either *for* or *of*** if you want to describe John as wise: the adjective can apply to John, and the wiseness may be due to his specific circumstances. I would use *for* if you want to emphasize the circumstances, *of* if you want to emphasize the principle of the action.

**In short:** In your example (3), you can use either *of him* or *for him*, depending on if you want to emphasize his specific situation or the general wise-ness of the action.

Unfortunately, English prepositions are some of the hardest and least consistent parts of the language.

Comment: The "for" under discussion is not a preposition but a subordinator. It's used in _to_-infinitival clauses that have a subject, as in the OP's example "It's hard [**for** you to make such a decision]", where "you" is the subject.